# xCode archived application isn't starting threads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode6, nsview

My application consists of 2 windows.

- The first window is the main window. It has an NSTextView and an NSView.
- The second window is the preferences page. It has an NSColorWell which would change the background color of the NSView on the main window via a shared instance of a class that I called MainDATA.

**When I press the build/run button in xCode, the app works perfectly.** Everything functions as is should.

When I archive and export my app, everything works excepts except for the background color change. When I open the app, the background is initially set as it should be, but when I change the color with the ColorWell, the background doesn't update.

The background updates its color using a thread that would call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` in another method by using `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this because like I said, everything works perfectly when testing the app.

Any ideas?

**Update:** Just found out that the reason it isn't updating is because threads aren't starting. Still not sure why.

Comment: Still having this issue after many archives.:(

Answer (score 0):

**Ahhh!**

That was frustrating...

I just found out that `while(true){}`loops **DON'T** work in archived applications. If anyone wants to explain to me why it is like that, let me know.

I hope this answer helps some people avoid the confusion and frustration I just went through:)